# Mongoid 3.1 eager loading, json, and field names

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

Recently updated to Mongoid 3.1 from 3.0.3 and this resulted in some broken code and confusion on my side.

Say you have a pair of classes with a belongs_to/has_many relationship, like so:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_many :members, :autosave => true
end

class Member
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :band
end
```

Saving all this to the database like so:

```
b = Band.new
b.name = "Sonny and Cher"
b.members << Member.new(name: "Sonny")
b.members << Member.new(name: "Cher")
b.save
```

I would in my API, be able to return a 'member' object like so:

```
m = Member.where(name: "Sonny").first
m.to_json
```

which yields the following, as expected:

```
{"_id":"<removed>","band_id":"5151d89f5dd99dd9ec000002","name":"Sonny"}
```

My client can request the full band object with a subsequent call if it wants to.  However, in some cases I DO want to include the referenced item directly.  With 3.0.3, I would just do the following:

```
m = Member.where(name: "Sonny").first
m[:band] = m.band
m.to_json
```

and this would add a new field with the full band information to it.  With 3.1, however (it may have started in earlier versions, but I didn't test), I now get this:

```
{"_id":"<removed>","band_id":{"_id":"5151dc025dd99d579e000002","name":"Sonny and Cher"},"name":"Sonny"}
```

So, it looks like the band info has been eager-loaded into the field?  Why is it stored under the key ':band_id' and not ':band'?  I guess ':band' is protected, but I still don't think the data should be stored under the ':band_id' key.  I suspect I am missing something here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an `:include` option for `to_json` like so:

```
m.to_json(include: :band)
```

The JSON will then have a key `band` with the Band object converted to JSON and `band_id` will still be present.

Comment: Thanks for this - it definitely works.  I will have to figure out how to adapt it in the case of using JSONP (in Sinatra).  I am still confused by the default Mongoid behavior though.  Filling band_id with the object feels broken to me.